# Remove BlurEffect before to use it with a button

Tags: swift, button, blur, effect, uiblureffect

I have a button, when I clicked it my background_image turns in blur effect.

```
 @IBAction func button_MainClicked2(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if button_MainCenter == button_viajes.center{
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.6, animations:

         {

            let blur = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.light)
            let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blur)
            blurView.frame = self.image_Background.bounds
            self.image_Background.addSubview(blurView)    

        })
        } else {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.6, animations: {
                // I want to remove blur effect as soon as i press the button again.
            })
        }
    }
```

How can I fix it to remove the effect as soon as I click back the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add `tag` to blur view like `blurView.tag = 1000` before adding it as subview, and then in animate block

```
for view in button_MainCenter.subviews {
    if view.tag == 1000 {
        view.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

edit:
not sure if it will be animated though. if not you can animate `alpha` of this view from 1 to 0 and then remove it.

edit:

```
 let blur = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.light)
 let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blur)
 blurView.tag = 1000
 blurView.frame = self.image_Background.bounds
 self.image_Background.addSubview(blurView)
```

Comment: If you don't want to loop through the subViews you can also just say `if let blurView = imageBackground.viewWithTag(tag: 1000) { ... }`

Comment: thanks man, but still not working. Where i need to add this tag?  need i to write this code before else? thanks a lot